# Remove vertical space at start of latex document

Tags: spacing, margins

I have this test file which is supposed to put `Hello there.` near the top of the page but it does not work in so far as there is still tons of vertical space at top. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\vspace{-10cm}
Hello there.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The reason for the vertical space is the default margins.  I would recommend using [the `geometry` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) for changing the page geometry.
With the `[showframe]` option to the geometry package you see that the text is actually already at the top of the page, but the page has a margin before the text starts (The gray bar at the top is the top of the page):

[image]

To see which dimensions you need to adjust you can use `\layout` from [the `layout` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/layouts).  So, with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}\layout
Hello there.
\end{document}
```

you get a nice image on page 1 that shows the various dimensions. From the top of this page you see:

[image]

So the dimensions you are interested in are (2) and (6).   From the bottom of the page we see:

[image]

Hence you need to adjust `\voffset` and `\headsep`.
Since `1.0in` is added to the dimension specified in `\voffset`, I set that to a negative value.
So, for instance setting this to:

```
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.75in}
\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}
```

you achieve:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
%\usepackage{layout}

\setlength{\voffset}{-0.75in}
\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}

\begin{document}%\layout
Hello there.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is nice but what if I only want to remove the extra space at the *beginning* of the document? These changes effect every page, not just the first one.

Comment: @j0equ1nn: The extra space at the _beginning_ of the document is going to depend on exactly how you have set up your document in terms of `\documentclass` and packages. I'd suggest you post a new question that with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduce the problem.  If it is relevant you can reference this question in your post.

Comment: That's all well and good but as this question is phrased, it does ask about reducing space at the beginning of the document, not just at the beginning of the first page.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a trick that accomplishes just what you asked with very minimal work, and resembles the attempt you referenced. You can make your "title" a removal of vertical space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{\vspace{-7cm}}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Hello there.
\end{document}
```

For more precise control over the margins, etc. of the whole document, there is @PeterGrill's answer, with the addendum that if you want the changes to only effect the start of the latex document, you need to mess with the documentclass.

Comment: Kind of dirty but it's the best and easier solution to remove on at beginning. By the way it also work if you still want to put a title like this : `\title{\vspace{-7cm}MyTitle}`

Answer (score 2):

To achieve a "Hello there" that is **really** in the top left corner of the paper, 
use the following bit of extreme code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=\paperwidth, textheight=\paperheight, noheadfoot, nomarginpar}
\setlength{\topskip}{0mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\begin{document}
Hello there.
\end{document}
```

It does away with the header, footer, margin paragraph, all related spaces as well as \topskip and \parindent.
Please, refer to the [geometry manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) and [this Cambridge University page](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/squeeze.html) for an explanation of the employed commands.