# moving an entire psmatrix environment

Tags: margins, psmatrix

For some reason, my psmatrix is too low on the page. I want to raise it to the top of the page.

I tried using an "offset" parameter:

```
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0,rowsep=1.3,offset=5]
```

but this apparently had no effect.

EDIT: Here is an MWE. Note that I use the first line, with the "makebox" commands, in order to set the column widths for the rest of the table (which is not shown here).

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0,rowsep=1.3,offset=5]
  \makebox[0cm]{} & \makebox[7cm]{} & \makebox[7cm]{} & \makebox[7cm]{} \\
  a
 &
  b
 & 
  c
 &
  d
\end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill done

Comment: But how is that "too low" on the page?

Comment: I want it to start closer to the top border of the paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `\usepackage{showframe}`, you will see that it is at the top of the page.  I think you want to adjust the margins:

[image]

If you want to reduce the top margin I would suggest using [the `geometry` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) to adjust that.

### References:

- [Remove vertical space at start of latex document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62448/remove-vertical-space-at-start-of-latex-document)

### Code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node} 
\usepackage{showframe} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=0,rowsep=1.3,offset=5]
  \makebox[0cm]{} & \makebox[7cm]{} & \makebox[7cm]{} & \makebox[7cm]{} \\
  a
 &
  b
 & 
  c
 &
  d
\end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```