# mdframed margins

Tags: margins, mdframed

I'm new using `mdframed` package and I stumbled upon with `\mdtheorem` so I created a definition and I want to use it at the beginning of the page, but the problem is that there is a space in blank between the page and the definition, I've tried with all the optional margins maybe I skip some option.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{Ejercicio}{
    linecolor=FireBrick,
    linewidth=2pt,
    innerlinewidth =2pt, 
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=DarkSalmon!20,
    leftline=false,
    rightline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    splitbottomskip=13pt,
    everyline=true,
    }
\mdtheorem[style=Ejercicio]{ejercicio}{Ejercicio}[section]
```

The result is the next and I don't want that big white space between[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if turned your code snippet a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: I think if you add `\usepackage{showframe}` you will see that it is at the very _top_ of the page. The space between the header is the normal margin spacing. I think [Remove vertical space at start of latex document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62449/4301) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text *is* already at the very top of the page as can be seen with the addition of [the `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe):

[image]

If you really want to reduce that further the space between the header and the top of the page is controlled via `\headsep`. So with `\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}` you get:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\mdfdefinestyle{Ejercicio}{
    linecolor=FireBrick,
    linewidth=2pt,
    innerlinewidth =2pt, 
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=DarkSalmon!20,
    leftline=false,
    rightline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    splitbottomskip=13pt,
    everyline=true,
    }
\mdtheorem[style=Ejercicio]{ejercicio}{Ejercicio}[section]

\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\newpage
\begin{ejercicio}
\lipsum[1]
\end{ejercicio}
\end{document}
```