# How to reduce top margin?

Tags: header-footer, margins

How can I reduce the margin between the first line of my document and the headerline?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
top=0.6in,bottom=0.6in,left=0.7in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\lhead{LH}
\rhead{RH}
\chead{CH}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfoot{LF}
\cfoot{CF}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
\large
First Line of my document.........
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\headsep=0pt`. For these kind of issues use `\usepackage{layout}` and then `\layout` immediately after `\begin{document}`. See for instance [Remove vertical space at start of latex document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62448/4301) and [Displaying page construction guides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42329/4301).

Comment: Ooh i am extremely sorry. Your suggestions...?

Comment: Is your issue solved? How?

Comment: Yes it was solved

Comment: @PeterGrill Would you like to add an answer or should we close as duplicate?

Comment: @CarLaTeX: I can certainly move the comment to an answer but think closing as a duplicate would be better.

Comment: @PeterGrill Voted to close, thanks!